# i am unable to uninstall firefox. When trying from Control Panel just get the message saying error launching installer

Tags: windows, firefox

I am trying to uninstall firefox, but get the message error launching installer. How do i go around this. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it manually. The instruction for this can be found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_Firefox).